# How to abort/cancel promise for first call during 2 consecutive angular service calls?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When 2 consecutive service calls are made through $http angular service on dropdown item selection and assume first call took time to return and second call return before first call resolve then it shows data of first call for second item selection.

So is there any way to abort first promise if service call made again before first call resolves.

For demo purpose I created sample [plunkar](https://plnkr.co/edit/MsWmvKF6bCHWcMXtarXQ?p=preview) which has dropdown with few items I added explicit condition where on selection of first item it took little longer time then other items.
So select first item and immediately select second item to reproduce the scenario, check favorite books display on screen.

Any help appreciated!

Service code:

```
app.factory('bookService', function($http, $q, $timeout) {
  return {
    getBook: function(id) {
      var promise = $q.defer();
      var timeoutSpan = id == 1 ? 3000 : 500;
      $http.get("favouriteBooks.json").success(function(data) {
        $timeout(function() {
          promise.resolve(data.filter(function(obj) {
            return obj.id == id
          }));
        }, timeoutSpan);
      }).error(function(msg) {
        promise.reject(msg);
      })
      return promise.promise;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: may be [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2616-aborting-ajax-requests-using-http-and-angularjs.htm) helps you

Comment: Trigger the second AJAX request only after the response of first request(synchronizing your request). In order to achieve it you can disable the dropdown with a loading symbol or image until the response for the first request is received. This is the one solution you can try.

Comment: Karthik, requirement is not to restrict user from taking action from user experience perspective. This will be the last option if there is no solution to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 ways to handle this scenario -

**Case 1:** Create global $q deffer object at service level and check whether this object has value/or not before making call to $http request. If this deffer object has value then resolved it explicitly. Plunkar code - [code snippet](http://plnkr.co/edit/ow5EGqEDvFZNaOK3wJVm?p=preview)

**Service Code:**

```
app.factory('bookService', function($http, $q, $timeout, bookConstants) {
  var service = {};
  service.mypromise = null;

  service.getBook = function(id) {
    if (service.mypromise) {
      service.mypromise.resolve(bookConstants.EXPLICIT_CANCEL);
      service.mypromise = null;
    }
    service.mypromise = $q.defer();
    var timeoutSpan = id == 1 ? 3000 : 500;
    $http.get("favouriteBooks.json").success(function(data) {
      $timeout(function() {
        if (service.mypromise) {
          service.mypromise.resolve(data.filter(function(obj) {
            service.mypromise = null;
            return obj.id == id
          }))
        }
      }, timeoutSpan);
    }).error(function(msg) {
      service.mypromise.reject(msg);
    })
    return service.mypromise.promise;
  }

  return service;

});
```

**Case 2:** Return $q deffer object as service response and maintain it at controller level. And in case of consecutive service call first check and explicitly resolve first service call then and proceed with other service call.
Plunkar code - [code snippet](http://plnkr.co/edit/XPem7M6dxu7ehSVlh49c?p=preview)

**Sample Code:**

```
$scope.getSelectedValue = function() {
    var id = $scope.selitem.id
    $scope.cancel();
    var bookPromise = bookService.getBook(id);
    $scope.requests.push(bookPromise);
    bookPromise.promise.then(getBookSuccess)
      .catch(errorCallback)
      .finally(getBookComplete);
  }

  function getBookSuccess(favouriteBooks) {
    if (favouriteBooks == 'User Cancelled') {
      return;
    }

    var books = '';
    angular.forEach(favouriteBooks, function(book) {
      books += book.bookName + ' '
    });

    $scope.selectedvalues = 'Name: ' + $scope.selitem.name +
      ' Id: ' + $scope.selitem.id + ' Favourite Book(s): ' + books;
  }

  function errorCallback(errorMsg) {
    console.log('Error Message: ' + errorMsg);
  }

  function getBookComplete() {
    console.log('getBook Has Completed!');
  }

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    if ($scope.requests) {
      angular.forEach($scope.requests, function(request) {
        request.resolve('User Cancelled');
        clearRequest(request);
      })
    }
  };

  var clearRequest = function(request) {
    $scope.requests.splice($scope.requests.indexOf(request), 1);
  };

}]);

app.factory('bookService', function($http, $q, $timeout) {
  var service = {};
  service.getBook = function(id) {
    var promise = $q.defer();
    var timeoutSpan = id == 1 ? 3000 : 500;
    $http.get("favouriteBooks.json").success(function(data) {
      $timeout(function() {
        promise.resolve(data.filter(function(obj) {
          return obj.id == id
        }))
      }, timeoutSpan);
    }).error(function(msg) {
      promise.reject(msg);
    })
    return promise;
  }
  return service;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following to wait for two or more promises `$q.all([promise1,promise2]).then(function(data){....});`

To access data of first promise just use `data[0]` the second promise return value is saved in `data[1]` and so on...